# If and append condition pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Im a complete newbie to python and pandas.I want to iterate through all rows in dataframe and check if the element in "Class" column is 1 or not ? How  to achieve this ?

Also I want to append those specific rows to a dataframe ? Like this

```
         emptydataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])
         data = pd.read_csv('data/trainData.csv')
         count = 0
         for rows in data:
            if(data[rows]["Class"] == 1):
                 count+= 1
                 emptydataframe.append(data[rows])
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Do **not** `.append` to a data-frame in a loop. That is **horribly** inefficient. Instead, use `pandas` indexing, that is the whole point of `pandas`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for telling me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly - you don't want to loop through your DF:

```
In [185]: df
Out[185]:
    A   B   C  Class
0   1   2   3      0
1   4   5   6      1
2   7   8   9      1
3  10  11  12      0

In [186]: new = df.loc[df['Class']==1]

In [187]: new
Out[187]:
   A  B  C  Class
1  4  5  6      1
2  7  8  9      1
```

Comment: You are amazing :) ,Thanks saviour.